# R) Having trouble finding numbers in Arrays

Tags: r, arrays, matrix

1. 

a) In the lecture we created a matrix named HairEyeColor. Rename this matrix HairEyeColor1.
b) Remove HairEyeColor from your Global Environment.
c) In RStudio datasets, find the dataset with the name HairEyeColor. View the dataset.
d) Write code to check that HairEyeColor is an array.
e) Write code to determine:
(i) the total number of respondents in the survey.
(ii) the total number of male respondents in the survey.
(iii) How many respondents have blue eyes?
(iv) How many female respondents have red hair?

Above is what I was given to code, and down below is what I have tried.

```
# Construct a vector of the data to be used in the matrix
HEC <- c(32, 11, 10, 3, 53, 50, 25, 15, 3, 30, 5, 8)
# Construct the matrix HairEyeColor
HairEyeColor <- matrix(HEC, nrow = 3, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE) # fill by row

# a) renaming the matrix to HairEyeColor1
HairEyeColor1 <- HairEyeColor
# b) Removing HairEyeColor from Global Environment.
rm(HairEyeColor)
# c) view HairEyeColor.
View(HairEyeColor)
# d) Writing code to check that HairEyeColor is an array.
is.array(HairEyeColor)
# e) Writing code to determine:
# (i) the total number of respondents in the survey. 
# (ii) the total number of male respondents in the survey. 
# (iii) How many respondents have blue eyes? 
# (iv) How many female respondents have red hair?
```

From c)viewing HairEyeColor, I was able to see arrays?(matrix?) with 32 rows so I tried nrow(HairEyeColor) for e)(i) but It didn't work. I also need help for other questions for e).

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the structure of the array to figure out what each of the 3 dimensions means.

```
str(HairEyeColor)

'table' num [1:4, 1:4, 1:2] 32 53 10 3 11 50 10 30 10 25 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  ..$ Hair: chr [1:4] "Black" "Brown" "Red" "Blond"
  ..$ Eye : chr [1:4] "Brown" "Blue" "Hazel" "Green"
  ..$ Sex : chr [1:2] "Male" "Female"
```

So the first dimension has 4 levels of hair, second dimension has 4 levels of eye color, and third dimension has 2 levels for sex.

```
 # e) Writing code to determine:
# (i) the total number of respondents in the survey.
sum(HairEyeColor)
# (ii) the total number of male respondents in the survey.
sum(HairEyeColor[,,"Male"])
# (iii) How many respondents have blue eyes? 
sum(HairEyeColor[,"Blue",])
# (iv) How many female respondents have red hair? 
sum(HairEyeColor["Red",,"Female"])
```

This should be self explanatory, you can access the different dimensions by putting in the different character factor levels in the appropriate place [x ,x ,x ]. Sum is just summarising the entries.